# Can I connect 4 12v fans to 1 USB cable plugged into a wall?

Tags: voltage, power, usb, 12v, fan

I bought 4 computer case fans for a project I'm doing.  I know how to wire just one fan to a USB plug that I put into my wall that makes the fan work.  How would I go about connecting 3 more fans to have a total of 4 fans without losing power?

Comment: It would probably work but the fan would run quite slow. Next just search for 5V fans to make your life easier. Or this time go buy another 12V power supply, which shouldn't be too expensive. But to answer you question, you just leave the speed monitoring and speed control pins empty and only connect the ground and power. Usually case fans can run at 5V but speed is very low. Also verify the amp number on the fan and make sure they don't overload the power supply.

Comment: If you can wire one and are happy with how it works, just wire the rest in parallel and hope that your USB plug can supply the current needed without losing power, if it can't find another way to power them (possibly a 12v power supply?)

Comment: I also have a 32v 2500Ma AC power adapter.  Would that would if I wired all the fans to that one power supply? Thank you for your guys help btw :)

Answer (score 1):

12v PC case fans are meant to be wired in parallel to the 12 volt output of a regulated supply.  The supply will need to be rated to provide at least the sum total of the amperage of the fans.

While they may have somewhat more tolerance than other components in a PC, you really should give them something close to to 12 volts - perhaps a little bit lower in voltage, but no higher than what it says on their label.  Beware of simple unregulated supplies where the output may balloon substantially over the nameplate under light load conditions.  And of course you must use a safely isolated supply with a DC output, not an AC output.

Fans like this are quite complex circuits internally, so wiring them in series to a higher voltage supply is not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (because you have not said) the fans are rated for 12 Vdc operation, there is no combination of series and parallel connections to a 32 V supply that will have all 4 fans operating with 12 V power source voltages.

Comment: If I connect them all in parallel to the 32v volts will they all work, Like it is safe to try?

Comment: @Wolfee22 if you connect them all in parallel to 32v they will all spin very quickly and then catch fire.

Comment: @immibis Oh, that's not good, would series work?

Comment: @Wolfee22 in series they will probably work, each one will only get 8v so they will go slower than normal. Also if one fan stalls the other ones will speed up.

Comment: @Wolfee22 series won't work because they are not linear loads. You will need to parallel each fan with a capacitor and a resistor to prevent burning them out when they are not energizing the motor coils.